# Unreal Engine 4 - iOS packaging error

Tags: ios, unreal-engine4

I can't package EMPTY UE4 project (standart BP 2DSideScroller) for IOS in 4.17.2, 4.18.3 and 4.19 (Preview 5).

Here is the error:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): ********** COOK COMMAND COMPLETED **********
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): ********** STAGE COMMAND STARTED **********
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): Creating UE4CommandLine.txt
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): Creating Staging Manifest...
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): CookPlat IOS, this IOSPlatform
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): UPL Init: None
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): ERROR: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Any idea what is wrong?

[Log 4.17.2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z_oHkQKgI1X2DbBM0ciDd5iQoOP2jDiR)

[Log 4.18.3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V6U1QwhkMgVvk-w6vr8lM1hvBLX7g8-T)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this problem and for me it was due to an issue with the UnrealBuildTool source file `IOSToolChain.cs`.  See https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/64882dd8e6a8711364a3857047d31167102ed846/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Platform/IOS/IOSToolChain.cs#L68 for the offending line.

The constructor is attempting to parse `IOSSDKVersion` as a float, but on line 25 this is set to the string "latest", causing the conversion to throw an exception.

This value is read via an XML build configuration file however, so setting the IOS SDK version directly in this file to a suitable value should fix the issue.

As an example, here's some XML that could be used in `<user>/AppData/Roaming/Unreal Engine/UnrealBuildTool/BuildConfiguration.xml`: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns="https://www.unrealengine.com/BuildConfiguration">
    <IOSToolChain>
        <IOSSDKVersion>11.4</IOSSDKVersion>
    </IOSToolChain>
</Configuration>
```

Hope that helps!